# javascript string to jquery to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add html code to a page.

I know this is permitted:

```
$( "<p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

But for longer strings, it would be useful to staore as javascript string.
Is something like this permitted?

```
x = "<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>";
$(x).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

### EDIT:

Maybe I oversimplified my question in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20577488/edit
I left out an inportant intermediate step.
I wanted to:

1. create a Javascript string `x`
2. assign `x` to a jQuery object (right term?)
3. perform jQuery stuff on this object
4. then append it

Example:

```
var x = "<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>";
template = $(x)
template.find('p').attr('class','something');
template.appendTo( ".inner" );
```

Comment: did you try it? Seems like simplest way to find out

Comment: you will have to use .html("yourhtml" +yourotherhtml)

Comment: works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/LqNs7/

Comment: You can do it http://jsfiddle.net/5msa2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery object from javascript string , then append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577616/jquery-object-from-javascript-string-then-append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use .find() on that string since find looks for the descendents and that string wrapped in jQuery is a element array. So try this:

```
var x = "<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>";
var template = $(x);
template.filter('p').attr('class','something');
template.appendTo( ".inner" );
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMpMg/2/)