# How to modify the elements in an html string before appending

Tags: jquery, string, selector

Maybe I oversimplified my question in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20577488/
I left out an important intermediate step.
I wanted to:

- create a Javascript string x
- assign x to a jQuery object (right term?)
- perform jQuery stuff on this object
- then append it

  ```
  var x = "<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> ";
  var template = $(x);
  template.find('p').attr('class','something');
  template.appendTo( ".inner" );
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `filter` instead of `find`. What you are looking for is at the root level so you need to use `filter` since `find` will look for descendants of `p` that are at the root level. Also you can use addClass to add a class unless you want to remove the existing classes.

```
var x = "<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>";
var template = $(x)
template.filter('p').attr('class','something');
//Or you can use 
//template.filter('p').addClass('something');
template.appendTo( ".inner" );
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snLRs/)**